How can I overload a constructor in a private nested class without getting a "Resource Not Found" error when I call Inherited Create?
I have a Managed Record named TEmail with a nested private class called TEmailForm that inherits from TForm. The idea is my email Record can create a modal form as needed for the user to type an email. I need the TEmailForm to have a reference to the TEmail Record that created it, so I overloaded the constructor for my nested EmailForm class like this:
constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; EmailPnt: PEmail); reintroduce;

EmailPnt: PEmail is a pointer to the TEmail Record that created the form.
I then implemented my constructor like this:
constructor TEmail.EmailForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent; EmailPnt: PEmail);
begin
    inherited Create(AOwner);
    Email := EmailPnt;
end;

It compiles fine, but when I get to the line that says inherited Create(AOwner);, I get the following exception:
Project EmailTester.exe raised exception class EResNotFound with message 'Resource TEmail.TEmailForm not found'.

If I move the TEmailForm class outside of the TEmail Record so it is no longer a private nested class, everything works perfectly, but I don't want the TEmailForm exposed publicly when you use the Unit. What can I do here to get this to work?

Have you tried to replace inherited Create(AOwner) with inherited CreateNew(AOwner)?

@AndreasRejbrand CreateNew does not cause the Resource Not Found error; however, it loads an empty form because it doesn't use the associated DFM file I have for the email form.

Okay, it wasn't clear to me if you actually used a DFM or if you populated the form dynamically at run-time.

Have you tried putting the TEmailForm class definition in the implementation section? Or is that not practical?

Can you provide a minimal example for us to investigate?

Won't this code call the constructor of the record TEmail and not the TEmailform?
